# No filters with sonata admin 3.1 after version update

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I've updated sonata admin bundle to the 3.1 version. Since then I do not have filters anymore. Does someone has the same problem?

This is my classAdmin:

```html
<?php

// src/CD/CarsBundle/Admin/ReservationsAdmin.php
// This code is made to custom the fields in the bloc 'Reservations' in the Admin Interface.

namespace CD\CarsBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;

/**
* 
*/
class ReservationsAdmin extends Admin
{
 
 // This code sets up the defaut sort column and order of the informations registered in this category.

 protected $datagridValues = array(
  '_sort_order' => 'ASC',
  '_sort_by' => 'id')
 ;

 // This code configures the filters section on the right side of the 'Réservations' page when we click on 'Liste'.

 /**
  * @param DatagridMapper $datagridMapper
  */
 protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
 {
  $datagridMapper
   ->add('id')
   ->add('reserve', null, array('label' => 'Réservé'))
   ->add('vehicules', null, array('label' => 'Véhicules - Immatriculation'), 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'CD\CarsBundle\Entity\Vehicules',
    'property' => 'immatriculation'
   ))
   ->add('heureDebut', null, array(
    'label' => 'Date et heure de début'), 'sonata_type_datetime_picker', array(
       'format'                => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
       'dp_side_by_side'       => true,
    'dp_use_current'        => false,
       'dp_use_seconds'        => false,
      ))
      ->add('heureFin', null, array(
    'label' => 'Date et heure de fin'), 'sonata_type_datetime_picker', array(
       'format'                => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
       'dp_side_by_side'       => true,
    'dp_use_current'        => false,
       'dp_use_seconds'        => false,
      ))
   ->add('nomAgent', null, array('label' => 'Nom de l\'agent'))
   ->add('prenomAgent', null, array('label' => 'Prénom de l\'agent'))
   ->add('direction', null, array('label' => 'Direction'))
   //commented because not needed here ->add('commentaires', null, array('label' => 'Véhicule affecté et commentaires supplémentaires'))
  ;
 }

 // This code configures the informations listed on the 'Réservations' page when we click on 'liste'

 /**
  * @param ListMapper $listMapper
  */
 protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
 {
  $listMapper
   ->add('id')
   ->add('vehicules', null, array('label' => 'Véhicules - Immatriculation'), 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'CD\CarsBundle\Entity\Vehicules',
    'property' => 'immatriculation'
   ))
   ->add('heureDebut', null, array('label' => 'Date et heure de début', 'format' => 'd-m-Y H:i'))
   ->add('heureFin', null, array('label' => 'Date et heure de fin', 'format' => 'd-m-Y H:i'))
   ->add('nomAgent', null, array('label' => 'Nom de l\'agent'))
   ->add('prenomAgent', null, array('label' => 'Prénom de l\'agent'))
   ->add('direction', null, array('label' => 'Direction'))
   ->add('reserve', null, array(
    'label' => 'Réservé',
    'editable' => true
   ))
   ->add('annulation', null, array(
    'label' => 'Annulé',
    'editable' => true
   ))
   ->add('remisage', null, array(
    'label' => 'Remisage',
    'required'=> false,
    'editable' => true
   ))
   //commented because not needed here ->add('commentaires', null, array('label' => 'Véhicule affecté et commentaires supplémentaires'))
   ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
    'actions' => array(
     'show' => array(),
     'edit' => array(),
     'delete' => array(),
     'email' => array(
      'template' => 'CDCarsBundle:Reservations:list__action_email.html.twig'),
    )
   ))
  ;
 }

 // This code configures the fieds in the form to add a booking.

 /**
  * @param FormMapper $formMapper
  */
 protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
 {
  $formMapper
   ->with('Généralités')
    ->add('heureDebut', 'date', array(
     'label' => 'Date et heure de début',
     'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy H:i',
     'years' => range(\date("Y") - 0, \date("Y") + 2),
             ))
    ->add('heureFin', 'date', array(
     'label' => 'Date et heure de fin',
     'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy H:i',
     'years' => range(\date("Y") - 0, \date("Y") + 2),
             ))
   ->end()
   ->with('Agent')
    ->add('nomAgent', null, array('label' => 'Nom de l\'agent'))
    ->add('prenomAgent', null, array('label' => 'Prénom de l\'agent'))
    ->add('dga', null, array('label' => 'D.G.A'))
    ->add('direction', null, array('label' => 'Direction'))
    ->add('email', null, array('label' => 'Email'))
   ->end()
   ->with('Demande')
    ->add('besoin', null, array('label' => 'Besoin'))
    ->add('nombrePersonne', null, array('label' => 'Nombre de personne'))
   ->end()
   ->with('Disponibilité')
    ->add('reserve', null, array('label' => 'Réservé'))
    ->add('annulation', null, array('label' => 'Annulé'))
   ->end()
   ->with('Remisage')
    ->add('remisage', null, array('label' => 'Remisage'))
    ->add('adresseRemisage', null, array('label' => 'Adresse'))
             ->add('dateDebutRemisage', null, array(
              'label' => 'Du',
              'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy H:i',
     'years' => range(\date("Y") - 0, \date("Y") + 2),
    ))
             ->add('dateFinRemisage', null, array(
              'label' => 'au',
              'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy H:i',
     'years' => range(\date("Y") - 0, \date("Y") + 2),
             ))
             ->add('emailDirecteur', null, array('label' => 'Email du Directeur'))
   ->end()
   ->with('Destination')
    ->add('destination', null, array('label' => 'Destination'))
   ->end()
   ->with('Motif')
    ->add('motifRdv', null, array('label' => 'Rendez-vous'))
    ->add('motifFormation', null, array('label' => 'Formation'))
    ->add('motifReunion', null, array('label' => 'Réunion'))
    ->add('motifCollecte', null, array('label' => 'Collecte'))
    ->add('motifInstallation', null, array('label' => 'Installation'))
    ->add('motifProgrammation', null, array('label' => 'Programmation'))
    ->add('motifDepannage', null, array('label' => 'Dépannage'))
    ->add('motifVad', null, array('label' => 'Visite à domicile'))
    ->add('motifAutre', null, array('label' => 'Autre motif'))
   ->end()
   ->with('Conducteur')
    ->add('conducteur', null, array('label' => 'Conducteur'))
   ->end()
   ->with('Mandataire')
    ->add('mandataire', null, array('label' => 'Mandataire'))
    ->add('nomMandataire', null, array('label' => 'Nom du mandataire'))
             ->add('prenomMandataire', null, array('label' => 'Prénom du mandataire'))
             ->add('emailMandataire', null, array('label' => 'Email du mandataire'))
            ->end()  
            ->with('Attestation')
    ->add('honneur', null, array('label' => 'Attestation cochée'))
   ->end()  
   ->with('Informations supplémentaires')
    ->add('commentaires', null, array('label' => 'Véhicule affecté et commentaires supplémentaires'))
    
    // Added 'choices' to be able to reach the vehiculesrepository to find the needed informations as known as the available vehicles depends on a specific date
    ->add('vehicules', null, array(
     'label' => 'Véhicules - Immatriculation',
     'choices' => $this->getVehiculesRepository()->getAvailables($this->getEntity())
    ),
    array(
     'class' => 'CD\CarsBundle\Entity\Vehicules',
     'property' => 'immatriculation'
    ))
   ->end()
  ;
 }

 // This code configures what is shown on the 'Réservations' page when we click on 'afficher'.

 /**
  * @param ShowMapper $showMapper
  */
 protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
 {
  $showMapper
   ->with('Généralités sur la réservation')
    ->add('id')
    ->add('heureDebut', 'date', array(
     'label' => 'Date et heure de début',
     'format' => 'd-M-y H:i'
    ))
    ->add('heureFin', 'date', array(
     'label' => 'Date et heure de fin',
     'format' => 'd-M-y H:i'
    ))
   ->end()
   ->with('Agent')
    ->add('nomAgent', null, array('label' => 'Nom de l\'agent'))
    ->add('prenomAgent', null, array('label' => 'Prénom de l\'agent'))
    ->add('dga', null, array('label' => 'D.G.A'))
    ->add('direction', null, array('label' => 'Direction'))
    ->add('email', null, array('label' => 'Email'))
   ->end()
   ->with('Demande')
    ->add('besoin', null, array('label' => 'Besoin'))
    ->add('nombrePersonne', null, array('label' => 'Nombre de personne'))
   ->end()
   ->with('Disponibilité')
    ->add('reserve', null, array('label' => 'Réservé'))
    ->add('annulation', null, array('label' => 'Annulé'))
   ->end()
   ->with('Remisage')
    ->add('remisage', null, array('label' => 'Remisage'))
    ->add('adresseRemisage', null, array('label' => 'Adresse'))
             ->add('dateDebutRemisage', null, array(
              'label' => 'Du',
              'format' => 'd-M-y H:i'
             ))
             ->add('dateFinRemisage', null, array(
              'label' => 'au',
              'format' => 'd-M-y H:i'
             ))
             ->add('emailDirecteur', null, array('label' => 'Email du Directeur'))
   ->end()
   ->with('Destination')
    ->add('destination', null, array('label' => 'Destination'))
   ->end()
   ->with('Motif')
    ->add('motifRdv', null, array('label' => 'Rendez-vous'))
    ->add('motifFormation', null, array('label' => 'Formation'))
    ->add('motifReunion', null, array('label' => 'Réunion'))
    ->add('motifCollecte', null, array('label' => 'Collecte'))
    ->add('motifInstallation', null, array('label' => 'Installation'))
    ->add('motifProgrammation', null, array('label' => 'Programmation'))
    ->add('motifDepannage', null, array('label' => 'Dépannage'))
    ->add('motifVad', null, array('label' => 'Visite à domicile'))
    ->add('motifAutre', null, array('label' => 'Autre motif'))
   ->end()
   ->with('Conducteur')
    ->add('conducteur', null, array('label' => 'Conducteur'))
   ->end()
   ->with('Mandataire')
    ->add('mandataire', null, array('label' => 'Mandataire'))
    ->add('nomMandataire', null, array('label' => 'Nom du mandataire'))
             ->add('prenomMandataire', null, array('label' => 'Prénom du mandataire'))
             ->add('emailMandataire', null, array('label' => 'Email du mandataire'))
            ->end() 
            ->with('Attestation')
    ->add('honneur', null, array('label' => 'Attestation cochée'))
   ->end()  
   ->with('Informations supplémentaires')
    ->add('commentaires', null, array('label' => 'Véhicule affecté et commentaires supplémentaires'))
    ->add('vehicules', null, array('label' => 'Véhicules - Immatriculation'), array(
     'class' => 'CD\CarsBundle\Entity\Vehicules',
     'property' => 'immatriculation'
    ))
   ->end()
   
  ;
 }

 // Added a custom action in the listfields = email

 protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
 {
  $collection->add('email', $this->getRouterIdParameter().'cd_cars_reservations');
 }

 // Used to go to pin on the vehiculerepository

 /**
  * @return \CD\CarsBundle\Entity\VehiculesRepository
  */
 private function getVehiculesRepository()
 {
  return $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('CDCarsBundle:Vehicules');
 }

 // Used to reach the enity

 private function getEntity()
 {
  return $this->getRoot()->getSubject();
 }

 
}
```

The entity:

```html
# ORM for the "Reservations" entity with fields and mapping between database tables

CD\CarsBundle\Entity\Reservations:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: CD\CarsBundle\Entity\ReservationsRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        heureDebut:
            type: datetime
        heureFin:
            type: datetime
        nomAgent:
            type: string
            length: 255
        prenomAgent:
            type: string
            length: 255
        dga:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
        direction:
            type: string
            length: 255
        email:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
        telephone:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
        destination:
            type: text
        reserve:
            type: boolean
            nullable: true
        annulation:
            type: boolean
            nullable: true
        remisage:
            type: boolean
            nullable: true
        adresseRemisage:
            type: text
            nullable: true
        dateDebutRemisage:
            type: date
            nullable: true
        dateFinRemisage:
            type: date
            nullable: true
        emailDirecteur:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
        conducteur:
            type: boolean
            nullable: true
        mandataire:
            type: boolean
            nullable: true
        motifRdv:
            type: boolean
            column: motif_rdv
            nullable: true
        motifFormation:
            type: boolean
            column: motif_formation
            nullable: true
        motifReunion:
            type: boolean
            column: motif_reunion
            nullable: true
        motifCollecte:
            type: boolean
            column: motif_collecte
            nullable: true
        motifInstallation:
            type: boolean
            column: motif_installation
            nullable: true
        motifProgrammation:
            type: boolean
            column: motif_programmation
            nullable: true
        motifDepannage:
            type: boolean
            column: motif_depannage
            nullable: true
        motifVad:
            type: boolean
            column: motif_vad
            nullable: true
        motifAutre:
            type: text
            column: motif_autre
            nullable: true
        commentaires:
            type: text
            nullable: true
        nombrePersonne:
            type: integer
            column: nombre_personne
            nullable: true
        besoin:
            type: string
            column: besoin
            nullable: true
        nomMandataire:
            type: string
            length: 255
            column: nom_mandataire
            nullable: true
        prenomMandataire:
            type: string
            length: 255
            column: prenom_mandataire
            nullable: true
        emailMandataire:
            type: string
            length: 255
            column: email_mandataire
            nullable: true
        honneur:
            type: boolean
            column: honneur
            nullable: true

    manyToOne:
        vehicules:
            targetEntity: Vehicules 
            inversedBy: reservations 
            joinColumn:
                name: vehicules_id
                referenceColumnName: id
            cascade:      [persist]

        user:
            targetEntity: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User  
            inversedBy: reservations
            joinColumn:
                name: user_id
                referenceColumnName: id

        pool:
            targetEntity: Pool 
            inversedBy: reservations
            joinColumn:
                name: pool_id
                referenceColumnName: id
            cascade:      [persist]
                
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

And my composer.json

```html
{
 "name" : "cosylvestre/flotte",
 "license" : "proprietary",
 "type" : "project",
 "autoload" : {
  "psr-4" : {
   "" : "src/"
  }
 },
 "require" : {
  "php" : ">=5.3.9",
  "symfony/symfony" : "2.7.*",
  "doctrine/orm" : "^2.4.8",
  "doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "~1.4",
  "symfony/assetic-bundle" : "~2.3",
  "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle" : "~2.3",
  "symfony/monolog-bundle" : "~2.4",
  "sensio/distribution-bundle" : "~4.0",
  "sensio/framework-extra-bundle" : "^3.0.2",
  "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler" : "~2.0",
  "sonata-project/admin-bundle" : "^3.1",
  "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle" : "3.0.4",
  "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle" : "^2.1",
  "sonata-project/user-bundle" : "3.0.1",
  "sonata-project/core-bundle" : "^3.0"
 },
 "require-dev" : {
  "sensio/generator-bundle" : "~2.3",
  "symfony/phpunit-bridge" : "~2.7",
  "phpunit/phpunit" : "4.8.24",
  "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle" : "^2.3",
  "liip/functional-test-bundle" : "1.0.*"
 },
 "scripts" : {
  "post-install-cmd" : [
   "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
   "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
   "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
   "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
   "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
   "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
  ],
  "post-update-cmd" : [
   "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
   "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
   "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
   "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
   "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
   "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
  ]
 },
 "config" : {
  "bin-dir" : "bin",
  "platform" : {
   "php" : "5.3.9"
  }
 },
 "extra" : {
  "symfony-app-dir" : "app",
  "symfony-web-dir" : "web",
  "symfony-assets-install" : "relative",
  "incenteev-parameters" : {
   "file" : "app/config/parameters.yml"
  }
 }
}
```

And I do not have the hours and minutes when I edit a page. I only have d-m-y. But I need to have h:m too.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you find your answer ?

Comment: Yes Put12co22mer2. We have to show the filters in the 3.1 version. So the answer you gave me was the good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Following the doc](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_list.html#filters) :**

> All filters are hidden by default for space-saving. User has to check
>   which filter he wants to use.
>
> To make the filter always visible (even when it is inactive), set the
>   parameter show_filter to true.

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('phone')
        ->add('email', null, array(
            'show_filter' => true
        ))

        // ...
    ;
}
```

I'll try to set the `'show_filter'` option....

---

For your hours and minutes, you've to use `datetime` instead of `date` field type

Comment: Filters are indeed hidden by default but available trough the "Filters" button. If they don't appear at all, maybe check if you have some conflicted template overrides.